# Meaning of best rank $k$ approximation of a matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm wondering what the meaning of the best rank $k$ approximation of a matrix $A\in\mathbb{E}^{m\times n}$ is.

I know that when talking about the best rank $k$ approximation, we measure this in terms of the Frobenius norm:

$A^* = \arg\min_{B, rank(B)=k} ||A-B||_F$

An application would be that $A$ stores the pixels of an image ($mn$ memory), and the rank $k$ approximation $A^*$ can then be stored with less space ($k(m+n)$ memory if we include the singular values in one of the tensor product vectors, instead of $mn$ memory).

Now, does this rank $k$ approximation also approximate $A$ the best as a linear map with a column space of dimensinality $k$ for all inputs? So i mean:

$A^*=\arg\min_{B,rank(B)=k} \int_{\substack{x\in\mathbb{E}^n,\\||x||_2=1}} ||Ax-Bx||_2 \, dx$

How would you prove this connection? I've been thinking of using the decomposition of the SVDs into sum of tensor product matrices, but I got stuck. Do you know a way to prove it?

In short I also mean: "For matrices, is being the closest in terms of coefficients equivalent to being closest in terms of a linear map (for a rank $k$ approximation)?"

Comment: One way to make that integral sensible is to take a surface integral over the unit ball

Comment: This already answers a bit my question intuitively. For the linear map of lower rank we'd like it to transform the unit ball in a very similar way as the original map. Since we can only choose $k$ singular values we'll choose the ones that stretch the ball most. Thus the two things might be equivalent. Would be nice to have a proof for it!